# Android C2DM Missing Registration Error?

Tags: php, android, curl, android-c2dm

I have implemented a C2DM client that requests the registration id from C2DM server. Once application gets registration id, applications stores device id and registration id in server database. I have implemented a PHP Server, but when ever i try to post message i get Error=MissingRegistration.

**PHP Server Code**

```
 $url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';

$body = 'Email=senderid@gmail.com&Passwd=password&accountType=GOOGLE&source=MyLittleExample&service=ac2dm';
$c = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec ($c);
$p = explode("Auth=",$page);
curl_close ($c);

$url = 'https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send';

$param = // Get Registration id from my sql
$mtype = 'important';
$msg = 'Hello';

$len = strlen($param);
echo $len;
function sendMessageToPhone($authCode, $deviceRegistrationId, $msgType, $messageText) {

        $headers = array('Content-length:300','Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='.$authCode );
        $data = array(
            'registration_id' => $deviceRegistrationId,
            'collapse_key' => $msgType,
            'data.message' => $messageText //TODO Add more params with just simple data instead           
        );

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
        if ($headers)
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);


        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
    }
$data = sendMessageToPhone($p[1],$param,$mtype,$msg);
var_dump($data);
```

According to the document Error=MissingRegistration occurs if there is no registration_id parameter in Post request. I even tried to run application by hard coding the Registration Id. Any help greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Well structured and clear question. I don't even know php and still I could understand everything. Deserves a +1. Still searching for the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! And here comes the possible solution (taking from a thread regarding notifications from another language I do not know): https://stackoverflow.com/a/8339611/1108032. Please read what he stated solved his issue. For me it looks like something like that should be failing you, because code-wise your code seems ok.

Comment: @Thank you, bt still struggling :(

Comment: What did you try from this post? have you tried registering again your device so that you refresh the registeration_id?

Comment: ya i tried, Actually after trying that i found out the fault, i.e if i set header in curl, post parameters are not sent to server. Thanks Once Again :)